# Map Reduce output show decimal number in format 5.7491844E7 etc

Tags: hadoop

My Java Mapreduce output shows me number in format 5.7491844E7 etc , Please let me know how can I get the correct result printed ?

**Output:**

```
Baby    5.7491844E7
Books   5.7450452E7
CDs 5.7410388E7
Cameras 5.7299596E7
Children's Clothing 5.7625016E7
Computers   5.7314756E7
Consumer Electronics    5.7453124E7
Crafts  5.7418584E7
DVDs    5.7649004E7
Garden  5.7539812E7
Health and Beauty   5.7480924E7
Men's Clothing  5.7621152E7
Music   5.749592E7
Pet Supplies    5.7197412E7
Sporting Goods  5.75983E7
Toys    5.7464028E7
Video Games 5.7513068E7
Women's Clothing    5.7434656E7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the below options

1. **decimalFormat**.

   DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
   df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);
   System.out.println(df.format(value));
2. **printf**.

   System.out.printf("%.9f", value);
   System.out.println();
3. **convert toBigDecimal and toPlainString().**

   System.out.println(new BigDecimal(value).toPlainString());
   System.out.println();
4. **String.format**

   System.out.println(String.format("%.12f", value));